# Reaver returns different WPS PSK and AP SSID each time it finds correct PIN

Tags: wifi, wireless, wpa2

I am testing a router for vulnerability, and I've noticed an interesting anomaly. It isn't the first time I noticed it, either. When entering the right PIN, Reaver will return with a different PSK and SSID each time. However, none will ever work. Here's an example of output:

```
~$ reaver ...
[+] Waiting for beacon from xx:xx:xx:xx:40:19
[+] Associated with xx:xx:xx:xx:40:19 (ESSID: xxxxxx7Y)
[+] Trying pin xxxxxx33
[+] WPS PIN: 'xxxxxx33'
[+] WPA PSK: 'bE8vLF121WVW8YJhiJSHU5VdYItwo5Y8Cv8KpWV9'
[+] AP SSID: 'NTGR_kRq'
```

---

```
~$ reaver ...
Reaver v1.4 WiFi Protected Setup Attack Tool
Copyright (c) 2011, Tactical Network Solutions, Craig Heffner <cheffner@tacnetsol.com>

[+] Waiting for beacon from xx:xx:xx:xx:40:19
[+] Associated with xx:xx:xx:xx:40:19 (ESSID: xxxxxx7Y)
[+] Trying pin xxxxxx33
[+] Trying pin xxxxxx33
[+] WPS PIN: 'xxxxxx33'
[+] WPA PSK: 'd45zG5uYHwsdu14ZEsioF9IWWzRrJPL2eWBrGYAkRikYThaC4'
[+] AP SSID: 'NTGR_A5VzduBlQv'
macai@macai:~$
```

These two attempts were made less than a minute within each other. The BSSID, PIN, and real ESSID have been blanked out. The generated PSKs and generated SSIDs, however, are both real.

So, the question raised is threefold:

1. Is this behavior a glitch, or is it deliberate technology?
2. Does this behavior have a name, and if so, what is it?
3. Are there any known vulnerabilities of this behavior?

Comment: That's interesting. I'm writing a blog about WiFi security and cracking WPS. I've completed the attack against 4 access points and not seen this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is very similar to [WIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_intrusion_prevention_system)s ([Wireless intrusion prevention system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_intrusion_prevention_system)).

> A [wireless intrusion prevention system (WIPS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_intrusion_prevention_system) is a network device that monitors the radio spectrum for the presence of unauthorized access points (intrusion detection), and can automatically take countermeasures (intrusion prevention).

Comment: I'm convinced that it's a WIPS of some sort, I was just being conservative and open-minded enough to consider the possibility that it's a glitch. Also, I want to know if this particular approach has a name and if it's vulnerable in some way. Would you know about any of that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is still vulnerable. Instead of using reaver you can make your own little script to brute force wps pin. Using a command 'wps_reg'. However if the router has wireless intrusion prevention system the wps feature will probably go to the (WPS)locked state after a couple attempts.

Answer (score 0):

The same access point can broadcast several SSIDs, so it looks like the one you're attacking is broadcasting two; and that reaver only shows (or gets from the AP!) a SSID at a time.

I would try with a different WPS cracking tool as well to check if you get similar results. 
You could try with [bully](https://github.com/bdpurcell/bully) or (more obsolete) [wpscrack](https://github.com/ml31415/wpscrack). Bully bundled with Kali Linux.

Please let us know, it is going to be interesting. :)